# compare string and find result with string replace not working

Tags: php, arrays, string, str-replace

I am trying to compare two strings in PHP. But I don't know why it is not working.

```
    <?php
$string1="what is the highest peak in the world";
$string2="The highest peak of World is";
$find_ans=1;
compare_string($string1,$string2,$find_ans);

function compare_string($str1,$str2,$find_ans)
{
    $str1=strtolower($str1);
    $str2=strtolower($str2);
    $skip_word="a,an,the,what,when,where,who,whom,which,whose,why,how,are,am,is,was,were,has,have,had";
    $word_arr=explode(",",$skip_word);
    $new_str1=str_replace($word_arr,'',$str1);
    $new_str2=str_replace($word_arr,'',$str2);
    echo $new_str1.'<br/>';
    echo $new_str2.'<br/>';
    $sim = similar_text($new_str1, $new_str2, $perc);
    echo $perc.'<br/>';
}
?>
```

The `similar_text` returned 70.769230769231 if I use resort, but it returned 83.333333333333 if I removed rsort. Here str_replace is not working.`$new_str1` and `$new_str2` print the same result as before.

**UPDATE**

I want to get results from `$string1` and `$string2` as "highest peak world" after doing str_replace.
But the problem is that if I change the strings as

```
$string1="what is the highest peak in india";
    $string2="The highest peak of india is";
```

Then the result is "highest peak dia" But not "highest peak India".

It was my mistake:  `$new_str1` and `$new_str2` print the same result as before.

Comment: You never said what the problem is. Not working is not descriptive. What do you expect as the output?

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to achieve than compare two strings. There is build in function strcmp() or you can use == to compare to strings.

Comment: `$new_str1 and $new_str2 printing the same result as before.`...really? That wasn't the case when I ran it - demo: https://3v4l.org/A5c2k . I guess that still isn't the output you wanted, though? I don't know, because you didn't tell us what you were expecting, or precisely what you think the problem is. See also [ask]. You can [edit] your post. Thanks.

Comment: `the result is "highest peak dia"` ...not with your current code - demo: https://3v4l.org/3CoV0. Have you changed it? If so, please edit it into your question. And please double-check everything before posting, so it doesn't waste time.